# Why is Pasuk 4:20 in Shemos out of chronological order?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, parashas-shemos

[Rashi on Parsha Shemos 4:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.4.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.4.20.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explains that "Chronological order is not strictly adhered to in the Scriptures" and that's why it's possible for the Pasuk to first say "and he returned to the land of Egypt" and then "and Moses took the staff of God in his hand".

But I'm sure there's a reason for the Torah to have this specific order. It's generally easier to write things as they happened. So if the Torah writes it out of order it must be for some reason. Do we know why it is written here like this?

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation:

End of Pasuk 20 and beginning of Pasuk 21 is:

> ...וַיִּקַּ֥ח משֶׁ֛ה אֶת־מַטֵּ֥ה הָֽאֱלֹהִ֖ים בְּיָדֽוֹ: וַיֹּ֣אמֶר יְהֹוָה֘ אֶל־משֶׁה֒ בְּלֶכְתְּךָ֙ לָשׁ֣וּב מִצְרַ֔יְמָה...

and Rashi explains on the words בְּלֶכְתְּךָ֙ לָשׁ֣וּב מִצְרַ֔יְמָה as follows:

> דע שעל מנת כן תלך, שתהא גבור בשליחותי לעשות כל מופתי לפני פרעה ולא
>   תירא ממנו

What is going to give Moshe the strength in his שליחות?

אֶת־מַטֵּ֥ה הָֽאֱלֹהִ֖ים

---

Reference:

**Pasuk 20:**
וַיִּקַּ֨ח משֶׁ֜ה אֶת־אִשְׁתּ֣וֹ וְאֶת־בָּנָ֗יו וַיַּרְכִּבֵם֙ עַל־הַֽחֲמֹ֔ר וַיָּ֖שָׁב אַ֣רְצָה מִצְרָ֑יִם וַיִּקַּ֥ח משֶׁ֛ה אֶת־מַטֵּ֥ה הָֽאֱלֹהִ֖ים בְּיָדֽוֹ
Rashi:
*וישב ארצה מצרים ויקח משה את מטה וגו': אין מוקדם ומאוחר מדוקדקים במקרא*

**Pasuk 21:**
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר יְהֹוָה֘ אֶל־משֶׁה֒ בְּלֶכְתְּךָ֙ לָשׁ֣וּב מִצְרַ֔יְמָה רְאֵ֗ה כָּל־הַמֹּֽפְתִים֙ אֲשֶׁר־שַׂ֣מְתִּי בְיָדֶ֔ךָ וַֽעֲשִׂיתָ֖ם
 לִפְנֵ֣י פַרְעֹ֑ה וַֽאֲנִי֙ אֲחַזֵּ֣ק אֶת־לִבּ֔וֹ וְלֹ֥א יְשַׁלַּ֖ח אֶת־הָעָֽם
Rashi:
*בלכתך לשוב מצרימה וגו': דע שעל מנת כן תלך, שתהא גבור בשליחותי לעשות כל מופתי לפני פרעה ולא תירא ממנו*

Comment: Would you consider adding a summary of the verses and commentary in Hebrew?